# MySQL C++ Connector - Linking error

Tags: c++, mysql, connector

Good day, I'm trying to use the MySQL C++ Connector, however, the following error pops up:

**undefined reference to `imp__ZN3sql5mysql19get_driver_instanceEv'**

I'm sure I linked everything correctly, else it wouldn't even recognize my other MySQL-related definitions (I think).

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <mysql_driver.h>

int main()
{
    sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;

    driver = sql::mysql::get_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "user", "password");

    delete con;

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas on what's causing that and / or how to fix it? I did already read some other threads here on SO, but none of them fixed my problem.

Comment: And your compile / link secuence is?

Comment: I'm using Code::Blocks and linking through the IDE itself. I'm linking libmysql and mysqlcppconn found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/).

Comment: Demangling `imp__ZN3sql5mysql19get_driver_instanceEv` with `c++filt` you get that `imp_sql::mysql::get_driver_instance` symbol is not found in your link chain. Check which flags and libraries are really used by Code::Blocks in your linking. (Note: I don't know Code::Blocks). Try to link manually using your favourite compiler, not through the ide.

Comment: I tried that already, in vain. I've also tried to build the libs myself, however, even in that case, some strange errors appeared while compiling, so I straightout gave up on that and decided to download VS2015 and use that (because the libs were built for VS), and guess what, even in that case, I had received the same error portrayed in the OP. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I've linked libs before and they worked flawlessly from the get-go. This error is really downing me, I just wanted to have some fun interfacing my program with a database.

Answer (score 0):

If you have g++ you could try from the Command Line:

g++ -Wall -Werror -Wno-long-long -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient -o outputFileNameOfYourChoice a.cpp

You could leave out some of the flags like -Wno-long-long or Werror although I wouldn't advise it just in case. In this case /usr/lib/mysql is where you find your mysql libraries, which might be different on your system so make sure you have the correct path although I believe that one should suffice..

Comment: I tried that but it says it cannot find "-lmysqlclient", but the lib file IS there.

Comment: Could you please search for "libmysqlclient.so" i.e. locate libmysqlclient.so and post the result

Comment: I do not seem to have "libmysqlclient.so".
Btw I made it run in VS2015 (Which I have just installed only to test if the connector worked at all), however, I'd rather use my other MinGW-using IDE, which's the one I'm having problems with.

Comment: Download and install "libmysql" for your system. Here's the link https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

Comment: Ok lets start afresh. What is your OS? On Linux you have to look for "libmysqclient.so" and in Windows you have to look for "libmysql.lib" for your static import library. Read more here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-building-clients.html

Comment: I'm on Windows, and as I said elsewhere, I linked all the necessary libs ("libmysql.lib" as well). Somehow it won't work on MinGW under Windows, neither can I build the libs myself since I'm also having problems with that, but it does work right out of the box on VS2015. I'm not sure what the problem is, I've noticed a ton of people have the same, exact problem concering said function on said environment (A quick look on Google or even here on SO proves that) but the solutions provided by the few who made it work, didn't work for me.

Comment: Can you please post the command you used to compile using MinGW.